# Getting a sprites 'real space' height

Tags: coordinates, sprite, scaling, coordinate-systems, timedelta

My Android game uses screen co-ordinates based on real space co-ordinates and my conversion goes like this:  All this is pseudo code, but I've highlighted as code

```
Real-space=(position/480);   (so for example 240/480 would be halfway across the screen)
Velocity = 1/Time;        (Time = seconds)
Real-space= Real-space+ (Velocity * delta time);
Screen Coordinates = Real-space* screen width / length
```

Now the problem I have is that in my game, I have the need to match the screen co-ordinates of 2 sprites, so they move together (with one on top of the other, so I'm simply using something like

```
Sprite1_Screen_Coords = (Sprite_2_Screen_Coords-Sprite1 Height)
```

(All hights are scaled so are relative to the screen size the app is currently being run on)

This works OK, but I have the need to match the 'real space' co-ordinates.

Obviously I can do something like:

```
Sprite1-Real-Co-ordinates = Sprite2-Real-Co-ordinates
```

which means they would be the same but what value would I subtract from this so it 'sits' perfectly on top of the other sprite?  How do I derive this missing value from/for the sprites I have?  So to summerise, I need something like:

```
Sprite1-Real-Co-ordinates = (Sprite2-Real-Co-ordinates - something representing the sprites height)
```

Thank all! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that I simply divided the sprite's scaled height by the current screen height and used that value - seems to work on the 3 resolutions I tested it on.